Flask Proxy Endpoint Returning Errors 408 and 405
I'm building a proxy endpoint in Flask that should handle various HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). However, I'm encountering two errors when I send requests:

408 Error (youtube.com):

408. That’s an error.
Your client has taken too long to issue its request. That’s all we know.


405 Error (google.com):

405. That’s an error.
The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL /. That’s all we know.

Here is my code:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, Response
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from http.client import HTTPConnection

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/iproxy', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def iproxy():
    try:
        url = request.form.get('inputData')
    except:
        return render_template('denied.html')
    
    parsed_url = urlparse(f'http://{url}')
    conn = HTTPConnection(parsed_url.netloc)
    path = parsed_url.path
    if parsed_url.query:
        path += '?' + parsed_url.query
    method = request.method
    body = request.get_data() if method in ['POST', 'PUT'] else None
    headers = {key: value for key, value in request.headers if key != 'Host'}
    conn.request(method, path, body, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    
    excluded_headers = ['content-encoding', 'content-length', 'transfer-encoding', 'connection']
    headers = [(name, value) for name, value in res.getheaders() if name.lower() not in excluded_headers]
    response = Response(res.read(), res.status, headers)
    
    conn.close()
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

